# Avoid Label Blinking Using Timer Control

Tags: c#, timer, label

im working on a code-editor (winforms)

and  im working on countline using a label something like this:

http://oi42.tinypic.com/iypoub.jpg

using this code:

```
private void timer_countline_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            updateNumberLabel();
        }

private void updateNumberLabel()
        {
            //we get index of first visible char and number of first visible line
            Point pos = new Point(0, 0);
            int firstIndex = rtb.GetCharIndexFromPosition(pos);
            int firstLine = rtb.GetLineFromCharIndex(firstIndex);

            //now we get index of last visible char and number of last visible line
            pos.X = ClientRectangle.Width;
            pos.Y = ClientRectangle.Height;
            int lastIndex = rtb.GetCharIndexFromPosition(pos);
            int lastLine = rtb.GetLineFromCharIndex(lastIndex);

            //this is point position of last visible char, we'll use its Y value for calculating numberLabel size
            pos = rtb.GetPositionFromCharIndex(lastIndex);


            //finally, renumber label
            numberLabel.Text = "";
            for (int i = firstLine; i <= lastLine + 1; i++)
            {
                numberLabel.Text += i + 1 + "\n";
            }

        }
```

timer set interval to 1 .
label dock = left .
now the problem was everytime i runs the program the label was blinking nonstop so fast .
even i change interval still the same thing .

but when i transfer the updateNumberLabel() to textchange event it still blinks everytime i add a
char on richtextbox or i press space .

like this: http://oi40.tinypic.com/a43gcy.jpg

now my question was how can i avoid this? or is there anyway i can do to avoid blinking of
the whole label when gets updated?

thanks a lot in advance for the help!

Comment: By blinking, do you mean flickering?  Or is it a steady blink?

Comment: @cokeman19 flickering fast when i use timer ... the time i pass to textchange event it flickers the time i add text on the richtextbox

Comment: You may benefit from enabling double buffering, either at the label level or possibly the form level.  There are examples of both here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3816362/winforms-label-flickering.

Comment: @cokeman19 your right sir ... about the docking but the problem was i still cant do it with the splitcontainer . i already did what the accepted answer says but its still flickerring nonstop

Comment: @cokeman19 it worked ... pls answer it and ill accept it sir thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may benefit from enabling double buffering, either at the label level or possibly the form level.

There are examples of both here: [winforms Label flickering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3816362/winforms-label-flickering).